# Fastlane match with 2 developer accounts

Tags: ios, fastlane, fastlane-match

Our app has multiple configurations and uses an enterprise developer account for some use cases and an appstore account for other use cases. I'm able to use match with both accounts by managing environment files, but run into a blocker when it comes to creating the developer certificate for the appstore account - it's attempting to use the Enterprise Account's certificate which obviously isn't available in the appstore account's portal.

I ran `fastlane match development --env enterprise_all` to match our enterprise bundleIds and generate a development provisioning profile for our enterprise account for each configuration and match that to a signing certificate.

I also ran `fastlane match enterprise --env enterprise_all` to do the same for the enterprise (In-House) certificate

I then ran `fastlane match appstore --env appstore_all` to get distribution assets for our appstore account

But when I run `fastlane match development --env appstore_all` to get dev assets for our appstore account, it's using the development certificate created for the enterprise account.

> Certificate 'VALUE' (stored in your storage) is not available on the Developer Portal
> [16:17:09]: for the user USER

How can I generate development certificates using fastlane for 2 different accounts using the same app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using a different branch for the appstore environment. Using this method after having already synced enterprise signing certificates (including development certificates), match will only use appstore signing resources for environments using the `appstore` branch and enterprise resources otherwise.

*.env.appstore_all*:

```bash
MATCH_GIT_BRANCH=appstore
```

`fastlane match appstore --env appstore_all`

`fastlane match development --env appstore_all`